# Can one hardcode convolutional filters to detect characters in a CNN?

Tags: python, localization, pytorch, conv-neural-network, object-detection

In Pytorch, you can hardcode your filters to be whatever you like.

At the moment, I'm doing text detection and I need to identify the location of a certain information. This information always starts with the letter '*X*'. **Could this radically improve detection performance if I hardcode the '*X*' filter?**

Here's what I have so far:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

kernel = (torch.zeros((9, 9)) + \
          torch.eye(9) + \
          torch.rot90(torch.eye(9))).type(torch.bool)*1

print(kernel)
```

```
tensor([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

We can visualize it like this:

```
plt.imshow(kernel)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Then, we can set the filter weights as such:

```
conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, 
                 out_channels=1, 
                 kernel_size=3, 
                 stride=3, 
                 bias=None)

conv.weight.data = kernel
```

Comment: do want to hardcode filters for all the alphabets? doesn't it make difficult for the model to generalize,also there more than one layer convolutions

Comment: is x always this exact shape with exactly the same pixel alignment? If so then you probably shouldn't be using a data driven method to detect in the first place.

Comment: It can be vertical/horizontal, or slightly rotated. It's always the same letter.

Comment: Generally a correlation filter isn't going to be robust to such variations.

Comment: There is no reason in hardcoding a filter. I highly doubt that this filter will really match the letter X in your input. There is no in variance against anything with this filter. You can just try it. Take some inputs and use the filter on it and visualize the output.

Comment: I think the example of hardcoding a filter is interesting although I agree with the other commenters that this is not going to save you much.  You still have to perform a convolution and these networks are designed to pick up on subtle patterns in the training data.  You can't hardcode the subtle patterns.

Answer (score 0):

No, I do not think this will improve detection performance.

Detection performance is usually known as "inference," that is, it is the process of running your network on new data where the training labels are unknown.  Hard-coding the weights will make absolutely no difference on the test performance of the network, as you still need to compute the convolutions.

We could also ask if it will improve the training performance.  Here, too, I expect that the answer is no.  One of the reasons that neural networks achieve the high accuracy they do is that they pick up on subtle patterns in the training data.  A real x on a real page is very unlikely to align with the pixels you set to 1 in your example.  Slight rotations or sub-pixel shifts or even different aspect ratios of the letter will change what the optimal filter will look like.

Indeed, one of the major changes in Machine Learning as we move into the Deep Learning era is that neural networks do a better job of picking the low-level features than a human engineer could do.

But thank you for the question -- just the code snippet of how to hard-code the value of a layer was useful to me!